# Scam with personal information

Tags: scams, ebay

I am trying to purchase a vehicle via craigslist and the alleged owner has moved and claims to have registered the vehicle with eBay motors. The alleged owner has claimed that my full name, address & phone number are needed in order for eBay to send me an invoice. Should I give the requested information or just move on.

Comment: Can they send you a link to the listing on eBay motors? Are they still wanting you to send them payment directly? It does sound fishy but there's not much they can do with that information that's typically public.

Comment: Given the title of your question, why is it actually necessary to ask?  Move on.

Comment: Are they still contacting you through CL or are they now contacting you through ebay? If they moved the listing to ebay, you should now be contacting them through the normal ebay channels.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is a scam.

If they were moving the sale from craiglist to Ebay, they would just send you the link for you to access. Registration is required at Ebay, but you register with ebay, not by giving personal information to a third party. [ref](http://pages.motors.ebay.com/buy/howto/bid-register.html).

What kind of scam is unknown, maybe identity theft or just that you would pay and never receive the vehicle.

Move on and never give out your personal information to private individuals online.